# How can I extend a regex pattern to prevent certain characters in the beginning and in the end?

Tags: html, regex, validation, email-validation

I am looking for a **basic** email validation using HTML5 pattern.
So far I have the following but I am struggling with the required rules below, esp. rules 1 and 3.

**Conditions:**

1. I only need to cover email addresses containing **letters (a-zA-Z), digits (0-9), underscores (_), dots / periods (.), dashes (-).
2. I only need to cover standard business email addresses such as firstname.lastname@domain.com, firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk, firstname.lastname@domain.de, firstname-secondname.lastname@domainPart1-domainPart2.de.
3. No need to cover Asian or Arabic characters and no need to cover characters not listed here.
4. No need to cover emails not containing dot / period.

**Required rules:**

1. First character cannot be underscore, dot / period or dash.
2. Last character cannot be underscore, dot / period or dash.
3. Cannot contain two dots / periods in a row.
4. Cannot contain spaces (also not as first or last character).

**My approach (not working):**

```
<input type="email" id="email" minlength="10" pattern="^(?!^\.\_\-)(?!.*[-_.]$)[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+$" required autocomplete="off">
```

Can someone show me how to do this right and also provide an explanation on the single parts?

Comment: Do you realize that `pattern` regex only works during data submitting? It does not prevent user typing any char into the field.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Yes, I realize that. What does this comment help me ?

Comment: This is not quite clear from your description what you expect. Try `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[_.-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*"`, see [an online regex test](https://regex101.com/r/o0QTte/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pattern="^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$"
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor at start
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `_`)
- `(?:[.-]\w+)*` - optional (0+) non-capture group of: dot or dash, followed by 1+ word chars
- `@` - a literal `@`
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?:[.-]\w+)*` - optional (0+) non-capture group of: dot or dash, followed by 1+ word chars
- `(?:\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,})+` - required (1+) non-capture group of: dot, followed by 2+ alpha chars (for TLD)
- `$` - anchor at end

Please consider supporting a `+label` sequence just before the `@` sign. Many people use that to bucketize email:

```
pattern="^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\+[\w.-])?@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$"
```

Here is a working example. The jQuery code is not needed in HTML5, added here because the code snippet does not seem to support it. The jQuery code adds a red border if the email is not valid. In an HTML5 environment, the input text is red if the email is not valid.

```js
$('#email').on('input', function(e) {
  let pattern = $(this).attr('pattern');
  let val = $(this).val();
  let regex = new RegExp(pattern);
  if(regex.test(val)) {
    $(this).removeClass('red-border');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('red-border');
  }
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Email:
    <input type="email" id="email" pattern="^\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})+$" required autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I noticed one minor issue: It detects two dots / periods in a row as invalid if this appears after the @ sign (which is intended) but it accepts two dots / periods in a row in front of the @sign (which I would like to exclude too). Is it possible to cover this, too ?

Comment: I tweaked the regex, please check. I recommend to always support the `+label` pattern, personally I avoid websites that do not accept this in my email address (spam measure).